# org messes up indentation levels when including files

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Consider the following setup:

```
$ cat contents.org 
#+INCLUDE: preamble.org
#+INCLUDE: introduction.org
$ cat preamble.org 
* Preamble
** subsection 1
** subsection 2
$ cat introduction.org 
* Introduction
** Subsection 1
** Subsection 2
```

Now, if I convert this to LaTeX:

```
$ cat compile.el 
(require 'org)
(require 'ox-latex)

;; Generate LaTeX
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "contents.org")
   (org-latex-export-to-latex nil nil nil t))
$ emacs -Q --batch -l compile.el
Saving file /home/nikratio/tmp/org-bug/contents.tex...
Wrote /home/nikratio/tmp/org-bug/contents.tex
```

Then the output looks rather wrong - everything in the second file is treated at the wrong indentation level:

```
$ cat contents.tex
\section{Preamble}
\label{sec-1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\label{sec-1-1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\label{sec-1-2}
\subsubsection{Introduction}
\label{sec-1-2-1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Subsection 1
\label{sec-1-2-1-1}
\item Subsection 2
\label{sec-1-2-1-2}
\end{enumerate}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to have the following output (ommitting the labels for brevity):

```
\section{Preamble}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
```

This is with org 8.3.4.

Comment: Does this work? (for each include directive): `#+INCLUDE: introduction.org :minlevel 1`